# Angular OpenLayers - Creating a vector layer

Tags: angularjs, vector, angularjs-directive, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

Hi guys I'm trying to create a vector layer using the angular-openlayers-directive. But a keep getting back this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'index' of undefined
    at addLayerBeforeMarkers
...
```

And this is the code I'm using to configure my map in my controller:

```
 $scope.layers = [
      {
        name: 'first',
        source: {
          type: 'ImageWMS',
          url: 'http://mymapserver/blah',
          params: {LAYERS: ''}
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'features',
        source: {
          type: 'Vector',
          source: null //I've tried without this option also.
        }
      }
    ];
```

And this is the HTML:

```
 <openlayers ol-center="ven" height="100vh">
        <ol-layer name="{{layer.name}}" ol-layer-properties="layer" ng-repeat="layer in layers"></ol-layer>
 </openlayers>
```

Why is it so hard to a Vector Layer to my map. All I want is to add and remove features later, so there isn't much sense in using a GeoJSON Layer, which I've seen in the examples quite a lot.

How can I add a vector layer to my map? How can I manually add some features to this vector layer? All of this using Angular.

Comment: You have to define a `ol.source.Vector` to the `ol.layer.Vector`. Is there a link to the docs (angularjs + ol3)?

Comment: Any update ?? I have the same problem